# I want my application to start with a splash screen and then proceed to open a website within the application itself

Tags: android

![i made a splash xml file where an image is loaded using linear layout, then made a splash java file to load the screen and passed to main activity code to open the website within the application itself. when i try to run the emulator it says " unfortunately website stopped working"][1]

Comment: Please post the relevant code and stacktrace. Check out [ask].

Comment: Emulators don't have mobile data connections?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give internet permission, for accessing internet API.

Please share code, for perfect resolution.